# How to consume a d.ts file's exported const types if the library's implementation is not integrated with the TS project?

Tags: javascript, typescript, definitelytyped

DefinitelyTyped has type definitions for many libraries, but often enough I cannot find a good way to use them when the Javascript implementation is separated from the Typescript, like when a library assigns itself to a property of the window through a

```
<script src="https://example.com/library.js">
```

tag, and when the JS bundle I'm managing is in another separate script. (Even though bundling everything together *including* the library is the standard and reliable method, assume for the sake of the question that I do not have the option of importing the library into my TS project proper.) For example, say I find a nice looking definition file for a library named `myLib`:

```
// my-lib.d.ts
export const doThing1: () => number;
export const doThing2: () => string;
export const version: string;
export interface AnInterface {
  foo: string;
}
export as namespace myLib;
```

In JS, I can use myLib by calling `window.myLib.doThing1()` and `window.myLib.doThing2()`. How may I import the shape of the whole `window.myLib` object so that I can declare it as a property of `window`? I can see that I can import the exported *interfaces*, eg:

```
// index.ts
import { AnInterface } from './my-lib';
const something: AnInterface = { foo: 'foo' };
console.log(something.foo);
```

This works, but I want access to the shape of the actual library object and its property values (the functions and strings and such), not just the interfaces. If I do

```
import * as myLib from './my-lib';
```

then the `myLib` identifier becomes a namespace, from which I can reference the exported interfaces, but just like above, I still have no access to the `export const` and `export function` shapes from `my-lib.d.ts`. (And, of course, trying to use the imported namespace to declare the library object doesn't work: `Cannot use namespace 'myLib' as a type.` Even if I could do that, that wouldn't necessarily be safe, because the library packaged for the browser may well be structured slightly differently from the library's Node export object)

If I manually copy and paste parts of the `d.ts` into my own script, I can hack together something that works:

```
// index.ts
declare global {
  interface Window {
    myLib: {
      doThing1: () => number;
      doThing2: () => string;
      version: string;
    };
  }
}
```

But this is messy, time-consuming, and surely not the *proper* way to go about doing something like this. When I encounter this sort of situation, I would *like* do be able to do something short and elegant like:

```
// index.ts
import myLibObjectInterface from './my-lib.d.ts'; // this line is not correct
declare global {
  interface Window {
    myLib: myLibObjectInterface
  }
}
```

Some definition files include an interface for the library object, like jQuery, which does:

```
// index.d.ts
/// <reference path="JQuery.d.ts" />

// jQuery.d.ts
interface JQuery<TElement = HTMLElement> extends Iterable<TElement> {
  // lots and lots of definitions
```

Then everything's just fine - I can just use `interface Window { $: jQuery }`, but many libraries not originally created for browser consumption do not offer such an interface.

As mentioned before, the best solution would be for the library's implementation to be integrated with the TS project, allowing for both the library and its types to be `import`ed and used without fuss, but if that's not possible, do I have any *good* options left? I could examine the properties on the real library object and add an interface to the definition file which includes all such properties and their types, but having to modify the semi-canonical source definition file(s) accepted by DT and used by everyone else feels wrong. I'd prefer to be able to import the shapes of the definition file's exports, and create an interface from them without modifying the original file, but that may not be possible.

Is there a more elegant solution, or are the definition files I've happened to come across simply insufficiently suited for my goal, and thus must be modified?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the module has an `export as namespace myLib` then module already exports the library as a global object. So you can just use the library as:

```
let a:myLib.AnInterface;
let b =  myLib.doThing1();
```

This is true as long as the file you are using the library in is not a module itself (ie it contains no `import` and no `export` statements).

```
export {} // module now
let a:myLib.AnInterface; // Types are still ok without the import
let b =  myLib.doThing1(); // Expressions are not ok, ERR: 'myLib' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.ts(2686)
```

You can add a property to `Window` that is the same type as the type of the library using an import type (added in 2.9 in believe)

```
// myLibGlobal.d.ts
// must not be a module, must not contain import/ export 
interface Window {
    myLib: typeof import('./myLib') // lib name here
}


//usage.ts
export {} // module
let a:myLib.AnInterface; // Types are still ok without the import (if we have the export as namespace
let b =  window.myLib.doThing1(); // acces through window ok now
```

**Edit**

Apparently the Typescript team has actually been working on something for this very issue. As you can read in this [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30776) the next version of typescript will include a `allowUmdGlobalAccess` flag. This flag will allow access to UMD module globals from modules. With this flag set to true, this code will be valid:

```
export {} // module now
let a:myLib.AnInterface; // Types are still ok without the import
let b =  myLib.doThing1(); // ok, on typescript@3.5.0-dev.20190425
```

This mean you can just access the module exports without the need for using window. This will work if the global export is compatible with the browser which I would expect it to be.

Comment: I don't understand why `typeof` can be safely used there

Comment: @CristianTraìna not sure what you mean ? `import('./myLib')` allows us to access the types in a module without importing. `typeof import('./myLib')` gives us the type of the import object without actually importing it.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! My consumers were always modules, since it's part of a larger project, I didn't think of trying to create a non-module file with side-effects only, which just feels strange to me.

Comment: So, to avoid modifying the original definition file, in a non-module, either create a (global) variable whose properties reference the library's (`const myLibObj = { doThing1: myLib.doThing1, ...`), or create a (global) interface which can be used later, `interface MyLib = { doThing1: typeof import('myLib').doThing1 ...`, allowing the library's location can be described more flexibly.

Comment: @Snow you don't need to spell out all the members of the library (although you can if you want), `typeof import('myLib')` represents an object containing all the value exports of the module (basically the type of `module.exports`). What you do with this type is up to you, typescript will only help you describe this in types, it will not in any way make sure the module is there at runtime (ie it does not care about how `myLib` comes to exist on `Window` at runtime, you have to make sure it's there, and from my reading of the question `window.myLib` already worked, it was just a typing issue)

Comment: @Snow also, just so make sure this point got across, the file containing the extra `Window` definition is just a definition file, no runtime behavior whatsoever.

Comment: Yep, it's just that the library's export in Node may not exactly match the object that's put onto the window in the bundled web version, so listing out the properties may be needed for accuracy.

Comment: @Snow that may be I don't know. If you want to pick some properties, `Pick` and `Omit` may help you write less. Especially if the `window` version just excludes one or two members from the node version, but this is all library dependent I guess

Comment: @Snow apparently the TS team has been working on exactly this scenario, see  my edit :)

Answer (score 3):

**What are you dealing with**

> when a library assigns itself to a property of the window

That's called a *UMD package*. These are the ones consumed by adding a link inside a `<script />` tag in your document, and they attach themselves to the global scope.

UMD packages don't have to be consumed this way — they can also be consumed as modules, using an `import` (or `require`) statement.

TypeScript supports both usages.

**How should UMD packages be typed**

```
declare namespace Foo {
  export const bar: string;
  export type MeaningOfLife = number;
}

export as namespace Foo;
export = Foo;
```

This definition tells TypeScript that:

- if the consuming file is a *script*, then there's a variable called `bar` in the global scope
- if the consuming file is a *module*, then you can import `bar` using named imports or import the entire namespace using the wildcard (`*`) import.

**What's the difference between a *script* and a *module*?**

A *script* would be a piece of JavaScript running inside a `<script />` tag in your HTML document. It can be inlined or loaded from a file. It's how JavaScript has always been used in the browser.

A *module* is a JavaScript (TypeScript) file that has at least one `import` or `export` statement. They are part of the ECMAScript standard and are not supported everywhere. Usually, you create *modules* in your project and let a bundler like Webpack create a bundle for your application to use.

**Consuming UMD packages**

A script, variables, and types are used by accessing the global `Foo` namespace (just like jQuery and `$`):

```
const bar = Foo.bar;
const meaningOfLife: Foo.MeaningOfLife = 42;
```

A script, the type of `bar` is imported using the *import type* syntax:

```
const baz: typeof import ('foo').bar = 'hello';
```

A module, the `bar` variable is imported using a named import.

```
import { bar } from 'foo';

bar.toUpperCase();
```

A module, the entire package is imported as a namespace:

```
import * as foo from 'foo';

foo.bar.toUpperCase();
```

**Global scope vs. window**

If such a library is typed correctly, you as the consumer don't have to do anything to make it work. It will be available in your global scope automatically and no augmentation for `Window` will be necessary.

However, if you'd like to attach the contents of your library to `window` explicitly, you can also do that:

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    Foo: typeof import('foo');
  }
}

window.Foo.bar;
```