# How to get VS Code / typescript autocomplete without importing the library

Tags: typescript

If a module (e.g. `moment.js`, `knockout`, or `big.js`) is included with a `<script>` tag e.g.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js">
</script>
```

that define a global property (e.g. `moment`, `ko`, `Big`, etc), how can one access/declare the types on `window` (or `global`) in Typescript.

For example

```
const x = moment()
const t = ko.observable()
const b = new Big()
```

How can one set the ambient type of these globals without including the entire `moment.js` library?  The objective is to have properly typed global references to be used by VS Code, and `tsc`, `ts-loader`, or `babel-typescript`.

In the case of `moment`, the types are exposed at `node_modules/moment/moment.d.ts`, but for other libraries (e.g. `knockout` or `big.js`) they're at `@types/[module]/index.d.ts`.

It feels like this would be quite common, but I haven't seen a good, working reference of how to accomplish this.

---

Here is the tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "ESNext",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "allowJs": true,
      "noEmit": true,
      "strict": false,
      "isolatedModules": false,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "noResolve": false,
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "paths": {
        "*": [
          "*",
          "js.packages/*"
        ]
      },
      "jsx": "preserve",
      "outDir": "dist/"
  },
  "include": [
    "js.packages/**/*.ts",
    "js.packages/**/*.tsx",
    "js.packages/@types/lib.d.ts",
  ],
  "files": [
    "services/app/src/entry.js"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Here's a `lib.d.ts`

```
declare global {
  type Bigable = Big | string | number
  interface Window {
    Big: typeof import('big.js'),
    moment: typeof import('moment'),
    Sentry: typeof import('@sentry/browser'),
  }
}
```

and here's how consumption should work:

```
const v = new Big(1)
const m = moment()
const s = global.Sentry()
const o = ko.observable()
```

which looks like this in VS Code (with the red underline indicating failures):

[image: failing types]

So knockout works because `@types/knockout/index.d.ts` has:

```
declare var ko: KnockoutStatic;
declare module "knockout" {
    export = ko;
}
```

whereas I've similarly declared a global `Big` on `interface Window`.

Unfortunately `Sentry` and `moment` (in this example) do not seem to work, and it's unclear why or what one might have to do to fix this.

Comment: Isn't this the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55778938/how-to-consume-a-d-ts-files-exported-const-types-if-the-librarys-implementatio ?

Comment: Since all of the types are UMD declarations, and since TypeScript automatically looks in both `node_modules/[package]` and `node_modules/@types/[package]` you shouldn't need to do anything in particular. Please post your `tsconfig.json`. It's perfectly possible to install the moment package just to get the types while still loading the implementation from a script tag at runtime.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I've posted quite a few more details, which I hope help illuminate.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Thanks; that's a great question too, and you can see specifics from edits I've made how the answers in that question fall short.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what it is you’d like to do (I.e. usage)?

Comment: @theMayer I'd like to generally have a better understanding of the types for globals, such as overcoming the specific problems with e.g. VS Code and `Sentry` and `moment` (as shown in the latter-half of the question).

Comment: OK, I added a note about autocomplete if that's what you're after. I use this technique for `moment` in VS Code, but I don't know which pattern Sentry will fall under.

Comment: the documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sentry/browser) would seem to indicate the `import * as Sentry from '@sentry/browser';` syntax.

Comment: @theMayer The trick is to avoid the `import` in each re-usable JS chunk.  We effectively just  need the types for VS Code / autocomplete.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have the right idea, you need to use an `import` type to get the types in an import, you need to declare variables in `global`. The problem is that you are declaring the properties on `Window`. While any key assigned to `Window` becomes a global variable typescript does not reflect this. You can declare the variables directly in the global scope.

```
declare global {
  export var moment: typeof import('moment');
  export var Sentry: typeof import('@sentry/browser');
}

const m = moment()
Sentry.init({}) // Sentry() does not seem like it should work according to docs
```

Comment: Thanks, that works.  Is this spelled out in the docs or anywhere else?

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt Not entirely sure .. there are docs about declaration merging https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html which mention global augmentation. But the specific issue with `Window` I'm not sure is mentioned in the docs (maybe some GH issue)

Answer (score 0):

The question is not terribly specific to one type of platform, but I'll tell you how I get `moment` working in Angular.

First, you shouldn't be loading from a script URL. You should run `npm install moment` to put it in your `node_modules` folder. This will ensure it gets packed up into the minified version of your application. You don't have to, but this is strongly recommended.

```
"scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
          "node_modules/moment/moment.js",
           ...
        ]
```

Regardless of the above, once you have the script linked in your `tsconfig` (or `angular.json`), usage is as simple as the following line at the top of the file:

`import * as moment from 'moment';`

I tend to use this syntax for most libraries which have an object, e.g. `shortid`, `linq`, and `lodash`.

Other libraries work better with `declare var` statements. For example, I've found jQuery to work better that way.

`declare var $`

**Autocomplete**

If you're looking for autocomplete, you need to have a `.d.ts` file loaded for the library. The npm package for `moment` comes with one, but some libraries need to have another npm package installed for this (e.g. `@types/lodash`, `@types/jquery`).

Visual Studio Autocomplete relies upon `.d.ts` files to identify types. The documentation for configuring this feature is located [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/javascript-intellisense?view=vs-2019), and it may be possible to configure it (see the note near the bottom).

Comment: Thanks @theMayor; I've used `<script>` tags for importing to simplify the question because what we're actually doing is webpack-chunks for globals for cache re-use across the browser main event loop, and web- and service-workers.  These libs effectively appear as globals, just like a script tag.  All that is somewhat beside the typescript point (we include 50+ JS libraries totalling tens of MB so caching/chunking is important to performance); the key element is we don't want to import a copy of every library in the app for every worker, which is what `import * as moment from 'moment'` does?

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt - I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish - doesn't webpack do this automatically? In any case, you're probably foregoing any type checking that VS Code may have to offer by doing so, and thus, yielding most, if not all, the benefit of Typescript in the first place.

Comment: Type-checking does not necessitate inclusion, much the way in C/C++ a `.h` file can provide the types of an external library.

Comment: But, what if you miss something? In any case, the question should be reworded to ask "How do I get intellisense without importing the library?" as that would have been a lot clearer from the get-go. Brief research indicates it is possible.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question heading.  I've tried all the options I've found, including the TS handbook, dozens of other references, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55778938, but after weeks of trying regularly I've ultimately succumbed to a bounty on StackOverflow as I've not yet hit the mark. 

Comment: ... which is particularly frustrating because, as you've noted, it seems like on brief research it is possible.

Comment: Yeah, I mean, this is sort of the age-old frustration with JavaScript. It seems to be true that something meant to attach itself to the global scope is "old-school" and thus, maybe it just isn't a thing that the folks who put typescript together gave much thought to?

Comment: I think the `import` model hits 99% of folks, but inability to include types from a `.d.ts` seems unfortunate. I noted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42234096, which is the list of workarounds for `moment.js`, a whole bunch of madness I'd like to avoid.  If you link that in your answer and can provide a way to solve the problem for a `Sentry` global, I'll mark this as correct and award the bounty, since I think the issue seems to be rather library-specific — and those are the only two non-working examples from the question.

Comment: I was thinking about this more today, and I wanted to go back and question the initial assumptions under which this question was asked. My app compiles down to 10MB pre-optimization. When using the `--prod` option on Angular, it brings it to just over 1.5MB.  Have you tried using automatic optimization? We do use quite a few npm packages in our code.

Comment: Yeah, that's a great suggestion.  We've a big code-base so we're slowly transitioning to libraries that fit with the more modern development styles (e.g. date-fns instead of moment.js), so this is really solving the transitionary pain.  It'll probably be years to complete the transition though, so we'd like to minimize the pain.  In the long term, I completely agree that tree-shakeable libraries that are properly imported are the best answer.