# Global type declaration in vscode for javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, .d.ts

I have a `/typings/$app.d.ts` looks like this.

```js
declare class App {
    test: object
}

export const $app: App;
```

[image]

But in order to use the intellisense, I have to auto-import it and it will generate a line like this on the first line of my javascript code.

```js
import { $app } from "../../typings/$app";
```

It will get in some error since it's a `d.ts` file.

Is there a way to make this `$app.d.ts` global like how the `window` does?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`declare var something` in `.d.ts` file top level scope is the keyword to expose global variable. Don't do `export` if you don't want to export anything.

```
declare class App {
    test: object
}

declare var $app: App;
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Yeah, I get it. But it's just a hobby of mine to unstuck people randomly. If you check my answer history you'll see I know how to explain properly. Just this one, I don't see much space to further explain anything.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I thought you just copied my code so I didn't even try it :/ my bad.

Comment: Okay..., it turns out you're right @ilke444. Without non-code text, ppl don't even bother to read :/

Comment: I edit. Hope it qualify to attract some upvotes now.

Comment: In order to avoid vscode doing the auto-import, you have to wrap your variable declaration in `declare global { ... }`, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56233344/429082 Without it, my vscode was just now offering to import the `.d.ts` file instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to make a comment on @hackape 's answer and also recommend (if you haven't already) to add a `tsconfig.json` file to your project's root. **Note that you can also add tsconfig if you don't want to use any typescript** (only for intellisense).

You can have a minimal file like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "typeRoots": ["./typings"],
    "outFile": "./justANameToMakeTSHappy.js"
  }
}
```

allowJs - so vscode would know to use the types also in the JS files.
typeRoots - let ts know where your types are.
outFile - so you don't get the error of 'can't overwrite file ****.js'